# How Rain fall data series adjusted with % irrigated area in the locality in turn calculate production risk

Tags: predictive-models, interaction, time-varying-covariate

I want to calculate the production risk based on rain fall data, both the variable is of time series data. we have % irrigated area also. if rain fall less area may be a irrigation by means of canal or bore wells. so how can i adjust this irrigated area in rain fall so that i can calculate production risk